# D runtime as DLL

Tags: windows, dll, runtime, d

Does anyone know if at least D runtime and Phobos for D 2 will be pre-built as DLLs or at least ready to be compiled in such a way?
Currently, as I understand, it will require to mark all relevant functions and/or classes as export. Couldn't find anything similar in current sources of DMD.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Currently, Phobos is available as pre-built LIB file, which is statically linked to your executable during compilation.

This has some advantages to DLL:

- Deployment - you can be always sure that your executable have appropriate runtime/gc/phobos available - the one which is tested with your application. There is new version of Phobos and D runtime every month, using DLLs in this case could cause versioning problems.

Disadvantages

- Executable size is slightly larger (100s of kb)
- Every "unit" exe / dll has its own garbage collector.

Why are you researching options of using DLL for Phobos? What insufficiencies do you seen in using LIB ?

Comment: 1. It's more natural for Win to have such things in DLL
2. Single instance of runtime and GC for the whole application
3. No binaries duplication

Comment: @target-san don't worry about D's runtime for a few more years.  Once it has been ABI stable for a year or so they'll start shipping DLL's.  Until then versioning a rapidly changing library just creates more problems than it's worth.

Comment: Honestly, unless the binary size is *really* becoming a problem, I wouldn't worry about DLLs. They are more trouble than they are worth.

Comment: DLL size isn't a concern here. As I've written above, the main thing is a single instance for GC. Just can't predict how will it behave on DLL boundary.

Comment: @Target-san: the stdlib is already split into the core and "user" parts and I think the API between then is more stable. I wonder if putting just the core in a DLL would cover your needs.